# List comprehension if/else and for iteration order

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that contains book chapters either as single chapters or chapter ranges delimited by commas, e.g. `1,2,4-6,12`.

Given this input `'1,2,4-6,12'`, I want a list  `['1','2','4','5','6','12']` as output

Something along the lines of:

```py
chps=[str(x) for x in chp_range(entry)) if '-' in entry else entry  for entry in chapters.split(',') ]
```

which doesn't work.

Function `chp_range('4-6')` returns a `range(4,6)` object.

I've tried a lot of variations, but still haven't been able to get the order of conditionals and iteration right. How can I get this code to work?

Comment: No need to obfuscate your code by trying to stuff that into a list comprehension, just write it out as a for-loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you were trying to do:

```
chps = [str(x)
        for entry in chapters.split(',')
        for x in (chp_range(entry) if '-' in entry else [entry])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7fCoIwFMbv9xTnbhvNQIsIoScRiWUzBzbH2Qn06demSPRdHTi/749faJjc6eoxxm7QngwGuAEvVaXOxUWVFWfsaXroBn9H7V5GBFkzSNIKHgl9ay@sIwXhGPxoSfCCS7kSaOiDDjZbxg@lZCwl5YomEIp5A7P6CcE4wgWsg33KHqn4PzhnSPw2rUYJtofUnn9bkhmDgWa9W9ky5jEtzbYgY/wC)

Comment: This is closest to what I was t thinking. Having said that I really appreciate all the comments and different code approaches given, and have on reflection, decided to use a more conventional (and readable) nested for loop to solve this. Thanks to you all for the awesome help :)

Answer (score 4):

If it has to be a one-liner, this should work:

```
>>> [str(x) for c in chapters.split(",") for x in range(int(c.split("-")[0]), int(c.split("-")[-1])+1)]
['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '12']
```

You can't conditionally nest your comprehensions, so your `chp_range` function is of little value when used in a comprehension.

Comment: Given readability is already compromised, you could also save yourself from computing `c.split("-")` twice: `[str(x) for c in s.split(",") for x in (lambda i: range(i[0], i[-1]+1))(list(map(int,c.split("-"))))]`... :)

Comment: @Julien I'm not that cruel.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to use list comprehension for the sake of, only if it's actually easier / more readable:

```
lst = []
for x in s.split(','): 
    if '-' in x:
        start, end = x.split('-')
        lst.extend([str(i) for i in range(int(start), int(end)+1)])
    else:
        lst.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain


def chp_range(entry):
    x, y = map(int, entry.split('-'))
    return map(str, range(x, y+1))


chps = [
    chp_range(entry) if '-' in entry else entry for entry in chapters.split(',')]
list(chain(*chps))
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use extend for range as follows:

```
string = '1,2,4-6,12'
string = string.split(',')
chapters = [] 
for i in string:
    if '-' in i:
        a,b = i.split('-')
        chapters.extend(range(int(a),int(b)+1))
    else:
        chapters.append(int(i))
print(chapters)
```

Comment: This is essentially the answer I already gave but adding the mistake of populating the list with `int` rather than `chr` as OP wants...

Comment: Probably we gave answer at same time xd

Answer (score 0):

Not a one-liner but if you are interested in a recursive solution. Please check it up.

```
a = '1,2,4-6,12'
inp = [num  if '-' not in num else [str(i) for i in range(int(num[0]),int(num[-1])+1)] for num in a.split(',') ]
ans = []

def flatten(inp,ans):

  while inp:
    tmp = inp.pop()

    if type(tmp) == str:
      ans.append(tmp)
    else:
      flatten(tmp,ans)

  return 

flatten(inp,ans)

ans[::-1]
```